# Trigger build from GitHub branch creation/deletion in TeamCity

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm trying to implement feature branch CI with TeamCity, and while I believe I know how to deploy feature branches based on [this guide](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Working+with+Feature+Branches#WorkingwithFeatureBranches-branchSpec), I can't seem to find how to trigger builds based off branch creation or deletion.

Basically, I need to simply create an IIS site when a branch is created, and delete the site when the branch is deleted.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Teamcity does not give any custom hooks to trigger actions on creation/deletion of branches. You can however run  a custom script that scans for new/deleted branches and then trigger custom teamcity targets via REST or consecutive build steps